# Intuition behind Quadratic Order of Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I am trying to understand Order of Convergence and specifically quadratic, cubic and so on.

The definition I came across was : $$\lim_{n \to \infty }  \frac{|x_{n+1}-L|}{|x_n -L|^q}=M$$

From there two cases where defined were :

1. $q=1$ and $M \in [0,1]$
2. $q\geq 2$ and $ 0< M < \infty$

I understand case $(1)$ as by dividing the current error with the previous error you can see how they compare.

However I am struggling to understand case $(2)$ and I got some questions :

- Why do we need to square or even cube the previous error?
- Why are there no limitations for $M$ in case $(2)$? Would a sequence still converge if $M$ was really large number?
- What would happen if say in Newton's method where convergence is quadratic we compared the errors like in case $(1)$?

Comment: I don't see any struggle, here, and the questions are unfocused. Why don't you *try* it on a "real" example, say Newton method for solving $x^2=2$ ($q=2$) vs. Newton method for solving $\sin x=0$ ($q=3$)? It's the only way to get what you call "intuition", doing math (not watching it done).

Comment: @ProfessorVector I ran a MatLab Script for Newton's Methods with different functions and for different values of $q=1,2,3,4$ and the intuition I got was that you need a measure. 
A constant value to compare your current approximation to your previous approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are there no limitations for  in case (2)? Would a sequence still converge if  was really large number?

The convergence rate only makes sense if the sequence converges... When $q=1$, if $M\ge 1$ there would be no convergence.

> Why do we need to square or even cube the previous error?

The convergence rate $q$ is a measure of how fast $x_n$ is converging to $L$. Imagine that $M=1$ and $|x_n-L|\leq 10^{-2}$. If $q=2$, we would have $|x_{n+1}-L| \leq 10^{-4}$ while if $q=3$ we would have $|x_{n+1}-L| \leq 10^{-6}$.

We are not "squaring" or "cubing", we are just trying to see if the inequality holds for $q=2$ or $q=3$.